# Closure Compiler Renaming Methods of External Libs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, typescript-typings, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I am creating a Chrome extension and compiling it using closure compiler, specifically [tscc](https://github.com/theseanl/tscc)

When I compile the code it's converting `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` into `chrome.b.a()` and causing it to throw the error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined

How do I prevent this from happening?

**tscc.spec.json**

```
{
  "modules": {
    "out": "src/background.ts"
  },
  "compilerFlags": {
    "language_out": "ECMASCRIPT_2019"
  },
  "external": {
    "chrome_extensions": "chrome"
  },
  "prefix": "dist/"
}
```

Comment: You probably need to use [an externs file for extensions](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js).

Comment: [Use Simple optimization instead of Advanced](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels?csw=1)